# Manifest Merger Failed when importing my aar library into project

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Iam new in developing android library.Recently there was a requirement to integrate some part of my app to other client app. For that, I have uploaded an aar format library through sonatype to maven repository.

But the problem arises when i integrate this library to other app.I have encountered some error like-:

Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/android/volley/Response$ErrorListener;

and many more like that.

The problem which I think so far is coming from the multiple dependencies defined in both app and library.

Is there anything which iam doing wrong in my library and how can we remove the duplicate library from the app.

I have tried many options like "multidex enable true and preDexLibraries = false" option but none of that attribute work.

Any help is appreciated.

My library app level gradle is-:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply from: 'maven-push.gradle'



android {
    compileSdkVersion 26

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            useProguard true
            //consumerProguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField "String", "BASEURL", PROD_SERVICE_URL
            buildConfigField "String", "MERCHANT_ID", MERCHANT_ID
            buildConfigField "String", "ACCESS_CODE", ACCESS_CODE

        }
        debug {
            buildConfigField "String", "BASEURL", STAGING_SERVICE_URL
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.jpardogo.googleprogressbar:library:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:4.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.7.0'
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.3'


    implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.17'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:disklrucache:2.0.2'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1'
    //compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

}
task deleteJar(type: Delete) {
    delete 'libs/jars/logmanagementlib.jar'
}

task createJar(type: Copy) {
    from('build/intermediates/bundles/release/')
    into('libs/jars/')
    include('classes.jar')
    rename('classes.jar', 'logmanagementlib.jar')
}


createJar.dependsOn(deleteJar, build)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In your library `AndroidManifest.xml` remove everything from `Application` tag:

```
<application/>
```

when you import the library in application, all `dependencies` you import in the library will be imported in the application so remove the any library you imported in library before in application gradle file

if there is a problem with merging the `AndroidManifest.xml` you can see the error in the `Merged Manifest`  tab in the bottom left corner

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for answering.You mean to say i should remove everything from my application tag  in manifest file in library,including all activities defined in my library project.But if i remove everything from manifest then how it will detect the activity defined in lib project.

Comment: Moreover merged manifest error is not coming ,the only issue which iam facing is of "Multiple dex defined " which probably coming from dependencies defined in my library project

Comment: you can call them in the Application Manifest